# Numpy accumulating one array in another using index array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

My question is about a specific array operation that I want to express using numpy.

I have an array of floats `w` and an array of indices `idx` of the same length as `w` and I want to sum up all `w` with the same `idx` value and collect them in an array `v`.
As a loop, this looks like this:

```
for i, x in enumerate(w):
     v[idx[i]] += x
```

Is there a way to do this with array operations?
My guess was `v[idx] += w` but that does not work, since `idx` contains the same index multiple times.

Thanks!

Comment: And *atomic* really is an inappropriate description for what you want to do.

Comment: How would you describe it? Hope new title is better.

Comment: @Constantinius, He accepted an answer for all but one of the questions he asked, which had one response which, while good, did not address his actual problem. Perhaps *you* should work on not drawing attention to the game aspect of this site.

Comment: I like the new description, much better. *Atomic* is often referred to in context of multi-threaded programming, so the question title was misleading.

Comment: @MikeGraham I accepted some good answers as response to his comment.

Comment: why do you want to use another operation beside the loop you have? speed concern?

Comment: @nye17 yes, exactly. This loop is one of the main bottle necks in my code. Also I came across this problem a couple of times and never found a good solution.

Comment: @Constantinius, the term "atomic" is not remotely limited to multithreaded programming. Although I agree it might not apply here, it is certainly a term with very broad use.

Comment: @AndreasMueller then you should either restructure your code to avoid this index-based summation or go for fortran or C wrappers. I don't think there is a numpy-native way to to that.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`numpy.bincount` was introduced for this purpose:

```
tmp = np.bincount(idx, w)
v[:len(tmp)] += tmp
```

I think as of 1.6 you can also pass a minlength to `bincount`.

Comment: I was aware of bincount but I didn'know it could handle weights! awesome :)

Comment: Please feel free to feel as my hero for the rest of the day :)

Answer (score 4):

This is a known behavior and, though somewhat unfortunate, does not have a numpy-level workaround. (`bincount` can be used for this if you twist its arm.) Doing the loop yourself is really your best bet.

Note that your code might have been a bit more clear without re-using the name `w` and without introducing another set of indices, like

```
for i, w_thing in zip(idx, w):
    v[i] += w_thing
```

If you need to speed up this loop, you might have to drop down to C. Cython makes this relatively easy.

Comment: Simpler still: `for i in idx: v[i] += w[i]`.

Comment: Without indices this should work, right?
The code you posted simply does ``v + w``, right? (If ``v`` is longer than ``w`` only the first ``len(w)`` elements are used.
Reusing ``w`` was an pretty bad typo, sorry.

Comment: @AndreasMueller, Sorry, I had a typo.

Comment: @larsmans, There was a typo in my code snippet which I have fixed. That code does not do the same thing as OP's code.