# Numpy : how to increment values of an indexed array?

Tags: python, numpy

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Numpy accumulating one array in another using index array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9790436/numpy-accumulating-one-array-in-another-using-index-array)

I have the following numpy arrays:

```
from numpy import array, zeros
A = array([10, 20, 30, 40])                                                                              
index = array([0, 0, 1, 1])
B = zeros(2)
```

For each value in `A`, I would like to increment the corresponding value in `B`, with a mapping given by `index`. With a loop, it gives:

```
for i in xrange(len(A)):
    B[index[i]] += A[i]
print B
```

At this point, I get `[ 30.  70.]` as expected.

Now how could I do that without a loop? (aka "the numpy way")

I intend to do the same operation over large arrays where the loop solution will certainly not be optimal.

If I do `B[index] += A`, it does not work as expected, for a reason explained [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays).

Writing a C extension looks a bit overkill, but is there something else to do?

Comment: you're right, thanks! Solution is as simple as B += bincount(index, A)

Comment: I would do `B += bincount(index, A, minlength=len(B))` just to be safe